# Package Restore Failed Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage

Tags: azure-storage, nuget-package-restore

I switched my 4.8 project to SDK format and am trying to restore the Nuget packages I need.
I can see that it is available in Nuget
[image: Nuget picture]

However when I try to install it I get
NU1101 Unable to find package Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage

If I have the following in my project

```
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage" Version="9.3.3.0" />
```

Then when I build I get an error.

> No packages exist with this id in source(s) nuget.org

[Update]

Now I see that the package version is deprecated

[image: deprecated icon]

However if I try installing Azure.Storage.Blobs 12.11.0 I get

> Error NU1605  Detected package downgrade: Azure.Core from 1.22.0 to
> 1.6.0. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.

Answer (score 0):

The following works.

```
<PackageReference Include="WindowsAzure.Storage" Version="9.3.3.0" />
```

When I right clicked the error in my source code VS2022 gave me the option of downloading from Nuget.